# HTC Legend 2.2 not recognized on windows 7

Tags: 2.2-froyo, windows, htc-legend

My HTC Legend is not recognized on Windows 7,

- I installed the last version of HTC Sync
- I added the following lines on the android_winusb.inf
  ;HTC Legend
  %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C97
  %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C97&MI_01

But still, my HTC can't be recognized

any idea ?

Comment: did you add that before you installed the drivers? just adding that to the file will not help. you need to add it, then install the drivers.

Comment: I added it after. I will try reinstalling the drivers,thank you !